# Insert random string into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, post

I try to insert the variable `randomString` into the table user2 into the column code, but it wont work. All other values are in the table, but the generated string wont. The column code have the type `varchar(8)`. Where is my mistake?

```
    <?php

session_start();
    $message = array();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

                if(isset($_POST['f']['country']) )
{
    $country = $_POST['f']['country'];
}

function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$randomString = generateRandomString();


        if (
            empty($_POST['f']['username']) ||                       
            empty($_POST['f']['password']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['password_again']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['email']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['firstname']) ||          
            empty($_POST['f']['lastname']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['phone']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['town']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['street']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['zip']) 
        ) { 

            $message['error'] = 'Es wurden nicht alle Felder ausgefüllt.';
        } else if ($_POST['f']['password'] != $_POST['f']['password_again']) {
            $message['error'] = 'Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.';
        } else {
            unset($_POST['f']['password_again']);
            $salt = ''; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
            }
            $_POST['f']['password'] = crypt(
                $_POST['f']['password'],
                '$2a$10$' . $salt
            );

            $mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', '', '', '');
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                $message['error'] = 'Datenbankverbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }
            $query = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO user2 (username, password, email, firstname, lastname, phone, town, street, zip, country, code)
                SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') as new_user
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT username FROM user2 WHERE username = '%s'
                ) LIMIT 1;",
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username']),                               
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['password']),                   
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['email']),          
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['firstname']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['lastname']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['phone']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['town']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['street']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['zip']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['country']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($randomString),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username'])
            );
            $mysqli->query($query);
            if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
                $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '//login.php');



                    $_SESSION = array(
                        'login' => true,
                        'user'  => array(
                            'username'  => $row['username']
                        )
                    );

            } else {

            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: First of all `session_start();` must be top of your page!!

Comment: `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['$randomString']),` change to `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['randomString']),`

Comment: $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['$randomString']), should be this $_POST['randomString']

Comment: Sorry. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using function `generateRandomString` anywhere. I don't understand its purpose quite well right now.

If `$randomString` has some value (input name in variable), you are looking for

```
$_POST[$randomString]
```

If you have `input` with name `randomString`, you are looking for

```
$_POST['randomString']
```

Anyway, currently you are trying to get value of `input` named **$randomString**. I bet you don't have input named like this.

If your variable is in single quotes, it is treated as plain string.

If you are trying just to save random string, use your function

```
$randomString = generateRandomString();
```

And save it

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($randomString),
```

Comment: I edit the code, but have can I call the function with that? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you right now. So you have input with `$randomString` name? Or you just want to save some random string. If just save, see end of my post.

Comment: I have no input with this name and I edit it how you said, but there is no string in my table.

Comment: You are overwriting `$randomString` value with empty value from `$_POST`. Remove `$randomString = $_POST[$randomString];` and `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[$randomString]),` should be `$mysqli->real_escape_string($randomString),`

Answer (score 0):

Few mistake in your code

1) `$randomString = $_POST['$randomString'];` change to `$randomString = $_POST['randomString'];`

2) `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['$randomString']),` change to `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['randomString']),`

And you not shows us how you call this `function`

```
generateRandomString()
```

in youe code??